# How to set a data context for listbox item in listbox item template different from the one set as itemsource in listbox

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, listbox

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="LstBoxTemplate">     
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<Image  Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,10,0" Visibility="{Binding isVisible,Converter={StaticResource ImageCtlVisibilityConverter}}" Source="/pjct;component/Images/im.png"/>
</DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ListBox x:Name=lstbox ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LstBoxTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of why you need this or what you are trying to do? The more information you provide with a question the easier it is to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You question needs more detail, and so I may be missing the point...

If your listbox is bound to a collection of custom objects that you control (aka a view model).  Then it should be fairly straight forward for you to add a property to the view model that contains the object that you want to bind your listboxitem to...

Comment: Pinging you because you seem to know something about this.  The code in the question just wasn't indented so it didn't get displayed at all.  I figured you'd want to have another go at answering, or delete your answer.